# How to write a common step definition which can be used by Given, When, Then etc. in cypress Cucumber

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, cucumber, gherkin, cypress-cucumber-preprocessor

I had recently integrated cucumber with cypress and added the [cucumber Full support plugin](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=alexkrechik.cucumberautocomplete) (VS CODE) to get the step suggestions when we develop feature files. Normally with the java-cucumber experience even though we define the step under **Given** when we write the feature file, the the step suggestions with pop up even if we are writing a **Then** scenario (Tool : Idea).
But in this case, if we define a step with **Then**

```
Then("User click on Contact Us",() => {
    cy.get('#basic-navbar-nav > div > a:nth-child(6)').click()
})
```

When we write the feature, the step suggestions will pop only if we start the step in feature with a **Then**

```
Feature: Login

    Scenario Outline: Sample

        Given User go to TestSite
        Then User click on Contact Us
```

I want to know if we can write a step def which will be common to all Given, When, Then etc. In java-cucumber Intellij-Idea support I think we have a * option insted of Given, When , then etc. Is there a workaround for this in cypress ?

Comment: did you found a solution ?

Comment: No mate. So as a workaround what I did was using the a single word "Given" for all the step defs. and when ever I right the step def, I use given and later I'm changing the feature in a readable way. It's a bit annoying but for now it's the best option that I have on this case.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve a generic step definition by using *defineStep* as follows:

```js
defineStep("User click on Contact Us",() => {
  cy.get('#basic-navbar-nav > div > a:nth-child(6)').click()
})
```

Just like Given, When, Then it can be imported from *cypress-cucumber-preprocessor/steps*

```
import { defineStep } from 'cypress-cucumber-preprocessor/steps';
```

You can use this step in your feature file then as Given, When or Then step like:

```
Feature: Login
    Scenario Outline: Sample
        Given User click on Contact Us
        When User click on Contact Us
        Then User click on Contact Us
```

Comment: In that case we need to call the step in the feature using  *

Comment: I was expecting to get the step suggestion irrespective of the way it is defined. I think it's an issue comes with the plugin for VS Code isn't it ?

Comment: In the feature file you can simply use the above step definition as Given, When or Then step, as you would normally do when you define it explicitly as one of them.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used that plugin before so I cannot answer the question specifically to that, but to get a more gherkin like syntax in my Cypress tests I commonly use something similar to the below example with context and nested describes.

```
context('Given ...', () => {
  describe('When ...', () => {
    it('Then ...', () => {
     ...
    })
  })
})
```

Comment: No mate, If we do this, the test will not be a cucumber test and I don't think we can write feature files using these methods. It will run as a normal cypress test but in the left panel it will look like a normal cucumber test. 
I want the step definition suggestions to popup when we try to write the feature irrespective of it being written under "Given or When or Then ... etc."